# Can't get this pesky CRTPish syntax right

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, crtp

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <template <typename... Ts> class SubA, typename... Ts>
class Helper : public A {
    static void bar();
    virtual void foo() override final {
        return bar();
    }
};

template <typename T>
class NiceA : Helper<NiceA, T> {    };
```

This compiles. **Edit:** If I now add:

```
template <>
void Helper<NiceA, int>::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Hi." << std:: endl;
}
```

this explicit instantiation compiles. But if I add instead:

```
template <typename T>
void Helper<NiceA, T>::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Hi." << std:: endl;
}
```

this fails with the error:

```
a.cpp:22:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Helper<NiceA, T>’
 void Helper<NiceA, T>::bar()
                            ^
a.cpp:10:7: error: declaration of ‘class Helper<NiceA, T>’
 class Helper : public A {
       ^
```

Why?

Note: Compiling with gcc 4.9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that this has nothing to do with CRTP, i.e. it has nothing to do with `NiceA` inheriting from `Helper`. Also, it has nothing to do with `Helper` inheriting from `A` or that virtual function.

Thus, here is the actual code for the question:

```
template <template <typename... Ts> class SubA, typename... Ts>
class Helper
{
  static void bar();
};

template <typename T>
class NiceA
{
};

template <>  // This compiles fine
void Helper<NiceA, int>::bar()
{
}

template <typename T>  // This does not
void Helper<NiceA, T>::bar()
{
}

int main()
{
}
```

Just saying, because by giving an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you make the job easier for those who would like to give an answer.

Now, why does it not compile? You cannot partially specialize a single member function. Period.

You need to partially specialize the whole class.

```
// Partially specialize Helper
template <typename T>
class Helper<NiceA, T>
{
  static void bar();
};

// Now implement the member function
template <typename T>
void Helper<NiceA, T>::bar()
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're simply mis-defining your member function:

```
template <typename T>
void Helper<NiceA, int>::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Hi." << std:: endl;
}
```

That would be the definition for a function template `bar<T>()` in `Helper<NiceA, int>`. But `bar()` is just a normal function, so you don't need to specify any template parameters:

```
template <> // <== nothing
void Helper<NiceA, int>::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Hi." << std:: endl;
}
```

Clang's error is much more helpful in this particular instance:

```
main.cpp:19:1: error: template parameter list matching the non-templated nested type 'Helper<NiceA, int>' should be empty ('template<>')
template <typename T>
^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Yeah... but ... see edit (I know I'm being a moving target here, +1 for your trouble)